# How to Filter letters in a string in Python

Tags: python

ok so I want to filter every string apart from `a` and print out the amount of `a` letters in the sentence:

```
import string
sentence = "The cat sat on the mat."
for letter in sentence:
      print(letter)
```

Comment: Could you show sample input and expected output. Did none of the SO question solve your problem.

Comment: what have you done so far? what have you tried? No SO user will write code for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print out the number of `'a'`, just:

```
sentence.count('a')
```

To filter out everything but `'a'`, use a comprehension:

```
filtered = ''.join(i for i in sentence if i != 'a')
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

First simply remove all `a`s before printing using `filter` function. Then, use `count()` to count the occurances

```
filter(lambda x: x != 'a', sentence)
#Out: 'The ct st on the mt.'
sentence.count('a')
#Out: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the number of 'a' appears in the string you can the simple count function from string as @Burhan mentioned.

```
sentence.count('a')
```

Defining a function to count number of 'a' in a string. Even though, you should avoid this but it is good to know how to count specific character or word in a string.

```
def count_specific_character(sentence):
    count = 0
    for character in sentence:
        if character == 'a':
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: "always good to have user defined function" - Actually, it's better to use built-in functions or built-in type methods when available. They're generally faster and more robust.

Comment: Thanks for lighting up on this @TigerhawkT3! I edited it!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to filter everything but the letter `'a'` is to use the built-in `filter` function

```
filtered = ''.join(filter(lambda char: char != 'a', word))
print(filtered)
```

And as already suggested use `str.count` method to count the number of characters in the string

```
word.count('a')
```